# How the clear ListPicker selection with SelectionMode Multiple

Tags: windows-phone-8

the orignal problem is :

I am able to clear the selection in listpicker dropdown buts its not resetting the text on corresponding textview.

Hers is how am clearing the selection:

```
if (Location.SelectedItems != null)
{
    Location.SelectedItems.Clear();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not understand your question completely. But if you want to clear the selection for listpicker Try this

```
 Location.SelectedItems = null;
```

Or for Single Item

```
 Location.SelecteItem = null;
```